# Display information in html from dataset?

Tags: html, flask, web-deployment

I have created a machine learning project ( movie recommendation system ) using flask .

It allows to search for a movie in the dataset and returns the id of the movie along with the ids of the similar movies

the main function is as :

```
def main():
    input=request.form['name']
    metadata=pd.read_csv('Datasets/final_metadata.csv',encoding='latin-1')
    features=pd.read_csv('Datasets/features.csv',encoding='latin-1')
    cosine_similarity=get_cosine_similarity(features)

    loc=is_there(input,metadata)
    if loc==-1:
        return render_template('not_found.html')
    id=metadata['id'][loc]
    rcmd=recommend(id,features,cosine_similarity)
    return render_template('details.html',id=id,movies=rcmd)
```

Here, get_cosine_similarity and recommend are custom function.

when i run this web app and search for any movie . i only get id of the movie and similar movies.

The html page is as:

```
<body>
    {{id}} <br>
    {{movies}}

</body>
```

The webpage looks like :
[image]

Is there any way in html that I could display the respective information of the movies with the given id in HTML page.

Comment: Your 'recommend' function just returns the ids in a list format? If you want more information about the movies, create a function that does so. Am I understanding your question correct?

Comment: i already had that option...can i do samething in html....??